# GPRS PPP connection issue on linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, gprs, ppp, pppd

I'm using Telit UC864-E GSM 3G modem. I want to run GPRS/3G connection over PPP on linux using pppd(ppp daemon).

I have a Telit UC864-E modem on my development board running embedded linux on Atmel SAM9 microprocesssor. The modem is interfaced to SAM9 and I have tested it by executing AT commands from a test program on SAM9. Even the GPRS/3G is working properly using the test application. But, I'm not able to establish a data connection over ppp on embedded linux on this board. Here is the log :

```
# pppd call gprs                                                                
Press CTRL-C to close the connection at any stage!                              
defining PDP context...        
AT                                                                                
OK                                                                              
ATZ                                                                             
OK                                                                              
ATE1                                                                            
OK                                                                              
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","www",,0,0                                                    
OK                                                                              
Serial connection established.                                                  
using channel 1                                                                 
Using interface ppp0                                                            
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS3                                                   
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xd2b80f00> <pcomp> <]
No auth is possible                                                             
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]                           
rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x2 00 00 00 00 00 00]                                     
sent [LCP TermAck id=0x2]                                                       
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x43ee1a75>]                     
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests                                            
Connection terminated.                                                          
Modem hangup
```

I have a evaluation board of same modem which is connected to my desktop PC running linux (ubuntu) on which i'm successfully able to run pppd to access the Internet. Here is the log :

```
harsh@ubuntu:~$ sudo pppd call gprs
Press CTRL-C to close the connection at any stage!
defining PDP context...
AT
OK
ATZ
OK
ATE1
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","www",,0,0
OK
Script /etc/ppp/peers/gprs-connect finished (pid 3723), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 3
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS0
Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/pap-secrets has world and/or group access
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x8579ad41>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x5 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xdab06202> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x5 <pcomp> <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x8579ad41>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x6 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xdab06202>]
sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x6 <auth pap>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x7 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xdab06202>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x7 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xdab06202>]
sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x8579ad41]
Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/pap-secrets has world and/or group access
sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="ubuntu" password=""]
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x8 magic=0xdab06202]
rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
PAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x3 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x4 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2]
sent [IPCP ConfNak id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x4 <addr 1.39.207.26> <ms-dns1 10.11.230.2> <ms-dns2 10.11.230.3>]
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x5 <addr 1.39.207.26> <ms-dns1 10.11.230.2> <ms-dns2 10.11.230.3>]
rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x3]
sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x3]
rcvd [IPCP ConfAck id=0x5 <addr 1.39.207.26> <ms-dns1 10.11.230.2> <ms-dns2 10.11.230.3>]
Could not determine remote IP address: defaulting to 10.64.64.64
not replacing existing default route via 192.168.170.2
Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
local  IP address 1.39.207.26
remote IP address 10.64.64.64
primary   DNS address 10.11.230.2
secondary DNS address 10.11.230.3
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up started (pid 3727)
Script /etc/ppp/ip-up finished (pid 3727), status = 0x0
```

The 'gprs' script is same on both the linux environments.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Does `/etc/ppp/peers/gprs-connect` exist on the embedded system? What are the permissions on all directories above that file?

Comment: And you have the same configuration, password files, etc? It's been a long time but IIRC this is what it would look like if you had the wrong authentication mechanism in the config.

Comment: @sarnold : Yes, /etc/ppp/peers/gprs-connect does exist on the embedded system and it's the same file as on the desktop PC

Comment: @tripleee : I have installed ppp on desktop using apt-get, and on the board the kernel is built using ppp support for busybox. The ppp versions might be different on both. Which configuration files should I verify ?

Comment: I noticed that there were no files in '/etc/ppp/' on the embedded system except the 'gprs' and 'gprs-connect' files in the 'peers' directory which i created manually. So I copied everything in '/etc/ppp/' directory of desktop to the embedded system.

Comment: Now I get the following output :                         
`# pppd call gprs                                                                
Press CTRL-C to close the connection at any stage!                              
defining PDP context...                                                         
Connect script failed                                                           
#`